# Finding indices of runs of integers in an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array with integers as entries. I need to find the indices corresponding to runs of integers in the array. For example if my array is `a = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]`, then the indices I want are `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]`. I have tried the following piece of code which uses a loop.

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 55, 56, 89, 90, 91, 92])
idx_cpy = idx

indices = []

while len(idx) > 0:
    sorted_idx = np.arange(idx[0], idx.max()+1)[:len(idx)]
    bool_equal = np.equal(sorted_idx, idx)
    true_idx = np.argwhere(bool_equal == True)[:, 0]
    try:
        indices.append(np.array(indices[-1]).max() + 1 + true_idx)
    except IndexError:
        indices.append(true_idx)
    idx = idx[true_idx.max()+1:]


"""
indices = 
[array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64), 
array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int64), 
array([ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], dtype=int64), 
array([14, 15], dtype=int64), 
array([16, 17, 18, 19], dtype=int64)]
"""
```

Although this works as expected, the variable `idx` in my actual code has large length and this takes a long time to complete. Is there a vectorized way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you want to do with the array. Could you give me another example of an array with what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MushfiratMohaimin, I need the indices of continuous runs of integers in the array. The first entry in the list `indices` corresponds to those indices in the actual array `idx` that have consecutive integers. Is that clear or did I make it worse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the "turning points" with `np.diff` and check where it differs from 1. To include end points, we pass `prepend` and `append` to it such that the difference isn't 1 in those places and they get counted too. Then a list comprehension with `np.arange` gives the final result:

```
>>> turnings, = np.where(np.diff(a, prepend=a[0], append=a[-1]) != 1)
>>> turnings

array([ 0,  4,  9, 14, 16, 20], dtype=int64)

>>> result = [np.arange(pre, nex) for pre, nex in zip(turnings, turnings[1:])]
>>> result

[array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64),
 array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int64),
 array([ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], dtype=int64),
 array([14, 15], dtype=int64),
 array([16, 17, 18, 19], dtype=int64)]
```